# Repair Python3 pip installation on WSL

Tags: python-3.x, pip, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I accidentally deleted a directory `~/.local/lib/python3.5/site_packages/pip` in my Ubuntu 16.04 installation on WSL.

After this I get errors when running pip3 like

```
 File "/home/harper/.local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
   from pip._internal.cli.main import main
 File "/home/harper/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 60
   sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
```

Now I tried to repair this by uninstalling pip3 and python3 and following both packages with apt

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt uninstall python3-pip python3
sudo apt install python3 python3-pip
```

But the command `pip3 --version` still shows the error message above.

What is the best way to do a clean reinstall of Python3? Is there any cache, probably the `~/.local/lib/python3.5/site_packages/__pycache__` directory that can be cleared or erased?

Comment: Remove `/home/harper/.local/bin/pip` and `/home/harper/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still have old `pip` script in your `$PATH` which `apt` cannot override. Remove `/home/harper/.local/bin/pip` and rehash `$PATH` with `hash -r pip`.